# facebook is redirecting to my site outside of facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I'm having trouble working with my redirect uri in the authentication.

If i set it to my site, the user will authenticate, because `$_Request['code']` is set, but then the user will be on my site, and I don't want that

If I redirect to apps.facebook.com/myapp, then `$_Request['code']` is not set, and the user won't authenticate, but just see a blank page.

is there any way to do this in PHP, I have code running before the page is rendered.

How do you guys solve this issue?

my login function:

```
public static function login($redirect) {
    $app_id = AppInfo::appID();
    $app_secret = AppInfo::appSecret();
    $home = urlencode(AppInfo::getHome());
    // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/
    // for a full list of permissions
    $scope = 'user_photos,publish_stream';
    session_start();
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
    // If we don't have a code returned from Facebook, the first step is to get
    if (empty($code)) {
      // CSRF protection - for more information, look at 'Security Considerations'
      // at 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/'
      $state = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
      setcookie(
        AppInfo::appID() . '-fb-app',
        $state,
        $expires = 0,
        $path = "",
        $domain = "",
        $secure = "",
        $httponly = true); 
      // Now form the login URL that you will use to authorize your app
      $authorize_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$app_id" .
      "&redirect_uri=$home&state=" . $state . "&scope=$scope";
      // Now we redirect the user to the login page
      echo("<script> window.location.href='" . $authorize_url . "'</script>");
      return false;
    // Once we have that code, we can now request an access-token.  We check to
    // ensure that the state has remained the same.
    } else if ($_REQUEST['state'] === $_COOKIE[AppInfo::appID() . '-fb-app']) {
      $ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "client_id=$app_id&redirect_uri=$home&client_secret=$app_secret" .
        "&code=$code&scope=$scope");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      // Once we get a response, we then parse it to extract the access token
      parse_str($response, $params);
      $token = $params['access_token'];
      return $token;
    // In the event that the two states do not match, we return false to signify
    // that something has gone wrong during authentication
    } else {
      echo("States do not match.  CSRF?");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Jakob can i see yur full code??
For what purpose yu are using that code??

Comment: @mogulzalp is there any way to do this in php, I have code running before the page is rendered, that would mean less load time to the user

Comment: I edited the post - I hope that was what you were asking for

Comment: @moguzalp - okay. Thank you for your answer though, it's the best I have so far :)

Comment: @Jakob I guess yu should add this code

$post_login_url = "www.yoursite.com";

try to add url of any specific page say www.yoursite.com/some- link

Comment: @user1159210 I'm not sure I'm following, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your app on Facebook, you can just use the `signed_request` parameter Facebook POSTs to your canvas url. You wouldn't need to read the `code` once the user has approved your app. Note that Facebook always sends this parameter, even if the current user hasn't approved your app (it contains less info then).

See the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)